# Contour Integration on a finite domain

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate by contour integration

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x^2-x^3)^\frac{1}{3}}$$

I am having trouble selecting the right contour for the problem as the usual problems involve selecting real axis from $-R$ to $+R$ and then closing with a semicircle of radius $R$. but that doesn't work here.

Comment: The Maple command $$int(1/(-x^3+x^2)^{1/3}, x = 0 .. 1); $$ outputs $ 2/3\,\pi \,\sqrt {3} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle{\large%
{\cal I}
\equiv
\int_{0}^{1}{{\rm d}x \over \left(x^{2} - x^{3}\right)^{1/3}} = ?}$

Let's rewrite the integral ${\cal I}$ as follows:
$$
{\cal I}
=
\int_{\infty}^{1}{-1/x^{2} \over \left(1/x^{2} - 1/x^{3}\right)^{1/3}}\,{\rm d}x
=
\int^{\infty}_{1}{1/x \over \left(x - 1\right)^{1/3}}\,{\rm d}x
=
\int^{\infty}_{0}{1 \over 1 + x}\,{{\rm d}x \over x^{1/3}}
$$
$$
-----------------------------------
$$
We integrate $\displaystyle{{1 \over \left(1 + z\right)z^{1/3}}\,,\quad z\ \in\ {\mathbb C}}$ ( see the integration path at the end ). $\displaystyle{z^{1/3}}$ is defined as $\displaystyle{%
\left\vert z\right\vert^{1/3}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\phi\left(z\right)/3}}$ where
$\displaystyle{z \not= 0}$ and $\displaystyle{0 < \phi\left(z\right) < 2\pi}$.
This is the $z^{1/3}$ branch cut. With this definition, the pole $z = -1$ becomes ${\rm e}^{{\rm i}\pi}$ such that $z^{1/3} = {\rm e}^{{\rm i}\pi/3}$. Similarly, on the path above the $x$ axis it's
$x^{1/3}$ and below it's $\left(x{\rm e}^{2\pi{\rm i}}\right)^{1/3}$. The residue at $x = -1$ is given by
$\lim_{x \to {\rm e}^{{\rm i}\pi}}{1 + x \over \left(1 + x\right)x^{1/3}}
 =
 {1 \over \vphantom{\Large A}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\pi/3}}$.

$$
2\pi{\rm i}\,{1 \over {\rm e}^{{\rm i}\pi/3}}
=
\int^{\infty}_{0}{1 \over 1 + x}\,{{\rm d}x \over x^{1/3}}
+
\int_{\infty}^{0}{1 \over 1 + x}\,
{{\rm d}x \over x^{1/3}\,{\rm e}^{2\pi{\rm i}/3}}
=
\left(1 - {\rm e}^{-2\pi{\rm i}/3}\right)\int^{\infty}_{0}{1 \over 1 + x}\,{{\rm d}x \over x^{1/3}}
$$

$$
{\cal I}
=
{2\pi{\rm i}
 \over
 {\rm e}^{{\rm i}\pi/3}\left(1 - {\rm e}^{-2\pi{\rm i}/3}\right)}
=
{2\pi{\rm i} \over {\rm e}^{{\rm i}\pi/3} - {\rm e}^{-{\rm i}\pi/3}}
=
{2\pi{\rm i} \over 2{\rm i}\sin\left(\pi/3\right)}
=
{\pi \over \sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}3\,}\,/2}
$$

The remaining integrals on the semicircles vanish out. The "big one" $\sim R^{-1/3}$
when $R \to \infty$. The "small one" $\sim \epsilon^{2/3}$ when $\epsilon \to 0$.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad%
\int_{0}^{1}{{\rm d}x \over \left(x^{2} - x^{3}\right)^{1/3}}
\color{#000000}{=}
{2 \over 3}\,\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}3\,}\,\pi\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
[image: Integration path. -1 is a pole.]

Comment: I could not follow the solution after the dashed line. How did you come up with 2*pi*i*exp(-i*pi/3)? And exactly which contour are you following?

Comment: I add some information about the contour integration.

Answer (score 0):

Try a contour shaped like this:

[image]

Comment: Not helping Sir. As the value over the contour comes out to be sum of residues at 0 and 1. And the same result when radius of both the circles tend to zero. As the integral in question gets canceled out by going back and forth on the domain (0,1)

Comment: @prat: Actually, it is helpful. Consider the function you integrate as holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}-[0,1]$; the integral is then computed using the residue at $\infty$.